# azure app service and asp.net core: origin has been blocked by CORS policy even AllowAnyOrigin

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I have developed an SaaS web app using angular 8 (front end) + asp.net core 2.2 (web api) and I have used below code to allow any origins on StartUp.cs file on asp.net core. After I deployed it azure app service, all good except for one page, I got following error message when I send a post request:

error message return to front end concole:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/api/stageProducts/addProduct' from origin 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

On Startup.cs

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod());
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was caused by some other code error which has nothing to do with CORS. Somehow, asp.net core shows CORS error message.

Answer (score 5):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/api/stageProducts/addProduct' from origin 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please check if you [enabled CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#test-cors) in `Startup.cs` of your back-end (web api) app, like below.

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod());

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseMvc();
```

> After I deployed it azure app service, all good except for one page, I got following error message when I send a post request

You are hosting your back-end (web api) app on Azure app service, so you can also specify the origins that should be allowed to make cross-origin calls to your app service on Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, this issue only happened on one page which downloads image from a site and upload it to my Cloudinary library. other pages like display products all good.

Comment: error message is 
"Http failure response for https://api.xxxxx.com/api/stageProducts/6211: 0 Unknown Error"

SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'https://xxxxxx.com' did not find 'https://xxxxx.com' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'https://api.xxxxxx.com/api/stageProducts/addProduct'.

HTTP503: SERVICE UNAVAILABLE - The service is temporarily overloaded.
(XHR)POST - https://api.xxxxx.com/api/stageProducts/addProduct

Comment: User * to enable all origins

Answer (score 0):

Could you give some more info? Like what error code do you get, because when you get a 500 server error it can be possible that there is a problem with your code. You can view a more detailed error message in your app service on azure also.

Comment: yeah, please see below screenshot for the error message:

SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'https://xxxxxx.com' did not find 'https://xxxxxx.com' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'https://api.xxxxxx.com/api/stageProducts/addProduct'.

HTTP503: SERVICE UNAVAILABLE - The service is temporarily overloaded.
(XHR)POST - https://api.xxxxxxx.com/api/stageProducts/addProduct

Comment: You can go into the azure "App Service" and if you go to "Diagnose and solve problems" and then search for "Application logs" you will normally get a detailed info about the error you are having.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have checked "diagnose and solve problems"-> application event log. I cannot find any error in relation to this. Can you please advise where asp.net core log the real error message? do I need to enable application logging on "app service logs" on azure app service? or how should I capture the detailed real error message? Thank you.

Comment: From my experience in the past, if there occurs an error in the application you will get it there...

Answer (score 0):

In your ConfigureServices try this

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
   {
      options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
      builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
     .AllowAnyHeader()
     );
   });
```

In your configure method do following

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I got below warning. I understand the warning. But I cannot specify individual origin since my app is SaaS app and I need to allow any custom domain name to use my web api. Can you please advise?
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[11]
      The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported.

Comment: Since you are using .Net core 2.2 , so i have updated my answer !